# can't type Persian number in android edit text

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext

I want to type phone number in Persian in android EditText . I set Farsi font to edit text but it didn't work . also i searched a lot but all of them discussed about set Farsi font to static text in Textview not typing in EditText . how can i achieve this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class CustomFontEditText extends EditText {


private Context context;
private AttributeSet attrs;
private int defStyle;

public CustomFontEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context=context;
    init();
} 

 public CustomFontEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      this.context=context;
      this.attrs=attrs;
      init();
 }

public CustomFontEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      this.context=context;
      this.attrs=attrs;
      this.defStyle=defStyle;
      init();
}

private void init() {
      Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
      this.setTypeface(font);
}
@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/farsi.ttf");
    super.setTypeface(tf, style);
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/farsi.ttf");
    super.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

**NOTE:**

Replace `farsi.ttf` with your font name and use `CustomFontEditText` instead of default `EditText` in your xml

Comment: If your project doesn't have an asset folder, you must create one:
new -> folder -> Assets Folder